# User types on library management system

Tags: java

I have to build a library management system and i've run into problems while trying to implement user types or profiles. I've already got a superclass user and two other subclasses of User, Student and Teacher, each with their own "characteristics". The thing is i have to implement 7 types of users (5 types of students and 2 types of clerks) based on the number of books they can borrow and the amount of time they can keep the books until they have to return them. Those are the only 2 differences between the classes.

How would you implement this? Inheritance? I'm looking for a clever way to implement this and i would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good rule of thumb, anywhere you see a noun in a project specification it's a good candidate for a class. If those nouns have relationships in the project spec, they probably aught to have one in your code too.

All of your people would fit in the category of a `User`so perhaps this should be an interface they would all inherit. Down from this they appear to fit into two categories, `Student` and `Staff` perhaps these should also be abstract classes / interfaces. Then you have your 7 concrete classes. 2 inheriting `Staff` and 5 inheriting `Student`.

So you'd end up with something like this.. 
[image]

Of course, this design depends on what every `User` must do, what every `Staff` / `Student` must do but I'll leave the very specific details to you.

Comment: That was my first option but i really can't help but feel kind of weird about having 7 really similar classes.

Comment: @PMMP Well, how similar are they? This design allows them to not depend on each other. If you have them too closely coupled and they change you'd have to redesign your system.

Comment: Take for instance the Student class. Two of its subclasses will be undergraduate and masters. For the purpose of this system the only difference between them is the number of books they can borrow.

Comment: @PMMP Well, for that case you could either have two separate classes or pass in the `maxBooks` value in the constructor.

Comment: @PMMP Just remember, by tightly coupling them together you could end up with undesirable consequences and/or needing to decouple them at a later time.

Comment: The maxBooks in the constructor was my second option but it kinda defeats the purpose the whole object oriented paradigm which you have in the first example you gave. Each option has pros and cons but i guess i'll go with the last one. Thank you for your input, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @PMMP Yes, it does. Which is why I personally would go with my original answer. Better having things loosely coupled. No Problem, Hope I helped! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a "class" per person, which really limits your design; because, if you want to add a student or teacher, you need to start writing a new class.

Classes are templates, and each template is used to construct an "instance of the class" or more specifically an "instance".  One template is typically used to construct more than one class (although it is not *necessary* for a class to be used more than once, using it once (or not using it at all) is fine).

So you could do

```
public class Student {

  private String name;

  public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public string getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

}

public class Staff {

  private String name;

  public Staff(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

}
```

As you can see, there is going to be a lot of duplication between staff and students.  `getName()`, `getAge()`, `getPhoneNumber()`, `getAddress()`, etc can easily be applied to both, which under this structure means that you would have to duplicate those methods for both `Student` and `Staff`.

What does both a staff member and a student have in common?  They are both `People`, and many of the common methods are common to all people.

```
public class Person {

  private String name;

  public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() { 
    return this.name;
  }
}

public Staff extends Person {

  public void teachClass(Class class) {
    ...
  }

}

public Student extends Person {

  public void attendClass(Class class) {
    ...
  }

}
```

This design also creates other issues, as it implies that a Staff member is not a Student, and a Student is not a Staff member.  In the real world, sometimes the Staff enrolls for classes, and Students can take on teaching roles (think teacher's aide).

The most flexible method actually doesn't create a structural differentiation between a Student and Staff, it differentiates between the two by ability.

```
 public class Person {

   public Person(String name) {
     ...
   }

   public void canTeach(Course course) {
     teaching.add(course);
   }

   public void attending(Course course) {
     attending.add(course);
   }

   public boolean isStaff() {
     return !teaching.isEmpty();
   }

   public boolean isStudent() {
     return !attending.isEmpty();
   }

 }
```

However, this structure is radically different from the example you are being presented in class, and it side-steps the lessons you really are supposed to be learning about inheritance.